# how to add images to multiple pages on a wordpress dynamically by the class name

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am currently adding images to the page new [on this website](http://satbulsara.com/luke-irwin/?page_id=175) but some images I would like to add to the various catagory pages such as new in, crop circles or childrens without having to upload to the different pages seperatley one at a time.

Is there a way to dynamically add the images to other relevant pages depending on the class of the image without having to upload to each page individually using php or ajax which would save lots of time.

or is there a plugin where I can add images to multiple pages at once?

I figure this is an ajax issue but am hoping there is a php wordpress solution.

It would be fab if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

umm.. Actually, I dont know any wordpress solution, If I were you, I would create a simple php which can do that logic for you and render a JSON file with your images struct?!